# undefined object error when using react navigation to go back a screen after deleting data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a simple location tracking app built with react native, react navigation and mongoose. A user can save a series of their locations in tracks, which are listed on their home screen. When a user presses on any of these tracks, they are taken to a 'track detail' screen, which displays more information about that track. This track detail page also contains a delete button:

```
<Button 
   title="Delete Track" 
   onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();   // go back to home screen
        deleteTrack(_id)   // function to delete the track via mongoose
    }} 
/>
```

The deleteTrack() function is very simple and uses Axios to connect to my backend, which uses mongoose to delete the record with the id provided.

```
 const deleteTrack = async (id) => {
        await trackerApi.delete("/tracks", { data: { id } })    
    }
```

Both of these functions work perfectly individually ie, the deleteTrack function removes the correct data via mongoDB and the navigation.goBack() successfully takes user back to the home screen.

HOWEVER, when these two functions are combined, I get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'track.locations')

This error is located at:
    in TrackDetailScreen (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer
...etc
```

What seems to be happening, is that the data is deleted on MongoDb, but the app is still trying to render the track detail screen with the deleted data. I'm not sure why this would be the case when I have left the screen via react navigation? I have tried a number of fixes, included conditional rendering and using await to delay the deleteTrack function until user has navigated away, but I get that same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you fetching the data in your home screen, are you using `useEffect` in that case add a dependency which changes when your data changes

Comment: What I have done is wrapped the entire return in if(track) else null statement, which doesnt seem particularly elegant but solves the problem.

Your adding dependency to useEffect was a good suggestion (thanks) but did not resolve the problem. My useEffect fetches ALL tracks. then a function within the component finds the selected track object and stores it in a variable. Storing it instead as state would solve the problem perhaps but again a bit of a messy solution I think.